# Android listen for ACTION_DOCK_EVENT

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I am trying to listen for dock change events per [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/docking-monitoring.html) and [ACTION_DOCK_EVENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DOCK_EVENT).

My receiver is never hit.

My code seems pretty simple, so I'm wondering is there a permission that is required for listening to dock events?  Am I missing something else related to ACTION_DOCK_EVENT?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:label="MyReceiver" android:name="path.to.MyReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

MyReceiver.java

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_DOCK_EVENT) {
      //Never hit :(
    }
  }

}
```

I am testing by plugging / unplugging my phone into a my AC power outlet and macbook pro.  I am using a Moto X (2nd Genration) with Android 4.4.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docks are a very specific type of accessory as seen in the [types of docks](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/docking-monitoring.html#DockType):

> - Car
> - Desk
> - Low-End (Analog) Desk
> - High-End (Digital) Desk

You'll note that none of these correspond with being plugged into a power source. For that, you'd probably want to [monitor changes in charging state](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#MonitorChargeState) using an Intent filter such as

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```